# Problemas com lentidão Delphi e FireDAC

Tags: delphi, postgresql, windows-8, firedac

Eu tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida em Delphi XE e faz um mês que alterei toda a estrutura de persistência que antes utilizava ADO para FireDAC.

Na compatibilização do novo componente de persistência eu utilizava a versão do Windows 7, e na última semana eu acabei formatando o computador e instalei o SO Windows 8.

Desde a formatação, a minha aplicação começou a ficar bem lenta. Eu depurei boa parte do código fonte e percebi que o gargalo da lentidão era devido a comunicação com o banco de dados (PostgreSQL 9.1).
Para utilizar o fireDAC na aplicação, tive que adicionar as seguintes DLLs: **libiconv-2.dll, libintl-8.dll e libpq.dll**

Eu tenho certeza que tem algo com os Windows, pois aqui na empresa onde trabalho os computadores com o Windows 7 que desenvolve o software está normal e todos os outros computadores que atualizaram para o Windows 8 começou ter a mesma lentidão.

Alguém já teve esse problema e/ou sabe alguma solução?

Comment: PostgreSQL costuma ser pesado para rodar numa maquina comum, você já testou com o banco rodando em um servidor? Já tive problema uma vez onde eu não conseguia executar as rotinas no banco local (travava) mas tudo ocorria bem no servidor.

Comment: Vou fazer esse teste, mas achei estanho porque antes de modificar para o Windows 8 tudo era bem normal e rápido.

Comment: Voltar para o W7 seria possível? Se sim, volte. É muito arriscado simplesmente mudar a versão do Windows quando trabalhamos com projetos que dependem do SO, como Delphi.

Comment: Chegou a usar algum profiler? Seria bom você tentar um para verificar exatamente onde. Sem informação de exatamente onde está a lentidão fica difícil diagnosticar.

Comment: Estou usando o PostgreSQL 9.1 e 9.3 e funciona muito bem. Ao invés de adicionar bibliotecas manualmente, por que você não instala o cliente do PostgreSQL 9.1 completo? E como está a configuração da conexão?

Comment: Altere novamente e utilize ZeosLib, que é rápida e OpenSource Free.

Answer (score 2):

Nesse [link](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/PostgreSQL-9-2-4-very-slow-on-laptop-with-windows-8-td5768279.html), havia uma pessoa com o mesmo problema. A solução encontrada, aparentemente, foi trocar a versão do SO por uma versão do Windows para servidor (2008 e 2003).

Talvez o que tenha causado o seu problema tenha sido a troca do **Windows 7** pelo **Windows 8**.

Ainda segundo o link, foi utilizada essa [tabela de apoio](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products-overview/postgresql-overview/supported-platforms-and-release-lif) para escolher a versão do SO a ser utilizada.

Sugiro você fazer um teste rodando sua aplicação com o banco em um servidor próprio para isso.